# .Jar Uses More RAM On One PC Than Another

Tags: java, deployment, ram

So I have a little issue. I have my desktop computer and my laptop. I am developping an audioplayer and I was doing  some tests on performance, and I noticed that on the desktop the program runs with 59mb of RAM on  taskmanager, while on my laptop it runs at only 48MB of RAM. I have no clue where this difference comes from, because the following statements are facts:

1. I have exactly the same JRE/JDK versions installed on both  machines.
2. Both my PC and laptop are 64-bit up-to-date windows 8.1 machines
3. Both .Jar files are the same (I even replaced one on my desktop with the one from my laptop)
4. In Netbeans itself (Yet again, both machines have same version and settings) on my desktop it runs at 50mb, and on my laptop at 35mb of ram

Same thing happens when I wrap the program in a .exe file with Launch4j and use a bundled java path (the one from my laptop). Again my PC runs with way more RAM than my laptop.

Does anyone perhaps have an idea where this huge difference in performance comes from? I'm at a loss, and I'm trying to get the RAM of my desktop to lower as well.

**important note**
I figgured out that this also happens when making a very basic program with a JFrame. On my laptop the empty frame uses only 18mb of RAM, on my pc it uses 28mb of RAM. I think that this is where the difference is coming from. But what are potential causes of this massive difference in performance?

**Specifications laptop**
8GB RAM
intel i5-5200U @2.2ghz
intel HD graphics 5500

**Specifications PC**
8GB RAM
intel i5-3470 @3.2ghz
NVIDIA gtx960

Comment: Do the desktop and laptop have different amounts of total RAM? The JVM might allocate more memory if the total amount of available memory is larger.

Comment: @Jesper both have 8gb of RAM. I'll post full specifications in the main-post.

Comment: Intel graphics use main memory. Nvidea doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Java 8 documentation, the default initial and maximum heap sizes depend on the amount of physical memory.  You are running the same versions of Java, the same OS and the same amount of RAM, so the initial heal sizes should be the same.

However, stuff happens within the JVM after that, and the chances are that there are significant differences.  For example:

- The two systems probably have different screen sizes and screen resolutions.  That could mean that the JFrames for the application have different dimensions (in pixels) and therefore occupy different amounts of memory.  (I'd guess you have a bigger screen on your PC than your laptop.)
- There could be differences in graphics cards, causing the respective JVMs to choose different video strategies (accelerated or not).  This could result in differences in heap and non-heap memory usage.
- There could potentially be differences on the audio side.

While the actual differences in (heap) memory usage could be small, they could be magnified by the GC's heap resizing algorithm.  When the heap is resized, the GC will attempt to grow it by a significant percentage.  If the heap space usage pushes the PC JVM to resize the heap one more time than the Laptop JVM, a small difference in actual heap usage could lead to a much larger difference in the respective heap sizes.

---

In short, I can't definitely say why there is such a big difference in memory usage, but there are a number of possible explanations.

But I wouldn't worry about this.  18Mbytes versus 28Mbytes is "small beer" on a system with 8 GIGABYTES of physical RAM.  We are talking about approximately 0.125% of each system's physical memory.

Comment: The resolution of the JFrame itself is 640x360 on both machines, so it probably does not come from there. Your 2nd point looks viable to me, it is very possible that due to a difference in graphics card the JVM chooses different strategies.

Answer (score 0):

in system memory and ram allocated by os and processes for particular task.
processor is responsible for allocating a multitasking and multiprocessing. can you check same file on same processor  and different system.

please check your both system configuration for processor.

Comment: I unfortinately do not have a a different system with the same processor as either my desktop or my laptop. Is there any other method?